# Listbox with checkboxes - code seeing every item IsChecked = true

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, loops

I have a WPF `Listbox` which contains a list of `checkboxes` which are all named as the names of other controls in another window.

When the `listbox` is looped by grabbing each item in `lst_control.Items`:

```
_details.controlIDs.Clear();

foreach(Control item in lst_controls.Items)
{
    if (item.IsChecked)

    //Add item to list
    _details.controlIDs.Add(item.controlID);
}
```

The code is fired on a check/uncheck of any of the `checkboxes` within the `listbox`. It sees each `item.IsChecked` as true - even if it is unchecked.

EG: Check the top box in the list, it sees it as `IsChecked = true`, but it also does for every other control in the list.

Weird behavior - has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Can you provide more of your actual solution? The XAML and more of the code behind. Is it button click etc.?

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. It turns out it was a binding issue. The app is mostly 'event driven' and relies on click events, selected item changed and so on. The case on the ListBox binding was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you're not going to go the full MVVM route, this issue is best resolved by separating the UI and the data layers in your application.

Make a data item class that includes an IsSelected boolean property, and set the ListBox's `ItemsSource` to a collection (eg `ObservableCollection`) of these items. For two way data binding, the data item class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

In your UI, make a `DataTemplate` for the ListBox's `ItemTemplate` property, that includes a CheckBox that is bound to IsSelected.

That way you can scan the collection of data items (using Linq or otherwise) to find those that are selected.